# Inserting a landscape table into a two-column document

Tags: tables, formatting, two-column, landscape

I have a table that takes up the length of a normal sheet of paper (when in landscape) and is only as wide as a single column. I would like to insert the table in landscape mode into one column of the LaTex document while still using the second column for the actual writing part. Any suggestions as to how this might work?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do this using the `rotating` package's `sidewaystable` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{22}{c}}
\toprule
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M &
N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V \\
\midrule
93 & 78 & 54 & 5 & 81 & 65 & 97 & 56 & 84 & 14 & 87 & 25 & 26 &
11 & 66 & 4 & 8 & 61 & 16 & 77 & 13 & 84 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a wide table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]