# Text not wrapping with table, landscape table

Tags: tables

I was hoping for some help regarding how I can get my table to not block the entire page. I want the second column of text to be on the other side (like conference papers do). However, on the page of the Table. Text is blocked.

[image: document]

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption{Exhaustive hyper parameter search}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{clllllllllllllllll}
<LOTS OF CONTENT>
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [Inserting a landscape table into a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145552/134144)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627553/wrap-text-around-rotated-table-and-caption